# Refreshing gridview after update

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble trying to get my gridview to refresh after I update it. The DB takes the updates and I can see them there when I manually refresh the page, but not when I click the update link to commit the changes.

I tried to call the function that fills the grid, I receive a js error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'firstChild': object is null or undefined".
It runs through the method and doesn't throw that error until after it has exited.

Is there another approach that I can take to refresh my grid after Update?

Here is the code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindCustodiansByProjectID();
            BindCustodianMedia(EditMediaClass.outRequestMediaID);
        }
    }

        private void BindCustodianMedia(string MediaID)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnString());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usps_displayEditMedia_CustodianMedia", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aspMediaID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = int.Parse(MediaID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(ds);

            grd_custodianMedia.DataSource = ds;
            grd_custodianMedia.DataBind();
        }

        protected void updateCustodianMedia_OnUpdateCommand(object sender, GridRecordEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnString());
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usps_updateCustodianMedia_EditMedia", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aspCustodianMediaID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = int.Parse(e.Record["CustodianMediaID"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aspMediaID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = int.Parse(EditMediaClass.outRequestMediaID.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aspCustodianID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = int.Parse(e.Record["CustodianID"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aspUploadPath", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = e.Record["UploadPath"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aspDataSize", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = e.Record["DataSize"];
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aspDataDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = e.Record["DataDescription"];

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //BindCustodianMedia(EditMediaClass.outRequestMediaID);    

        }
```

Comment: You will have to post your code, by the way the jscript error is the browser stating an error not your server side code.  To rebind the grid simply get your data (via dataset or datatable) and set it to your gridview's datasource property.  Something to this effect: `Dataset ds = GetMyData(); myGridView.DataSource=ds; myGridView.DataBind();`

Comment: After refreshing your grid you need to rebind your grid.

Comment: What you are doing exactly ??...Please post your code.

Comment: After your update routine you need to rebind your datagrid.

Comment: //BindCustodianMedia(EditMediaClass.outRequestMediaID); this line tried to do that, but it throw the js error. How should I construct this? -JohnH

Comment: @jpavlov - its not an issue with your server side code, in addition, that part is okay, it is a javascript issue, use chrome developer tools or firebug to find out what javascript is crying about.  Something is going out of what with the generated html of what you are doing.  Also try your site in chrome or firefox, it may help you pinpoint your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript error, try to debug with `Firebug` or IE developer tools and find out exactly which line is causing you the issue. You are trying access a property "firstchild" from an object which is null. With this information it is very hard to tell which could be the exact problem.